# How do I run this in eclipse?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I run this in eclipse?
This is my first javaFx Program using eclipse, but I can't get it to run, I need help!
I have this on my vm arguments
--module-path C:\Users\Claudia\OneDrive\Escritorio\javafx13-//11\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.control,javafx.fxml  but it throws an exception like  the  fallowing one:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.control not found

```
//code
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test1 extends Application {

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // title to my full name
        primaryStage.setTitle("Claudia Villatoro");
        // display layout
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        /// create variables
        Button button = new Button();
        Label label = new Label();
        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        Circle circle2 = new Circle();

        /// display 2 buttons
        pane.add(new Button("Hi!"), 1, 0);
        pane.add(new Button("Hello"), 2, 0);
        // create and set a scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // display 2 labels
        label = new Label("This is my first label");
        pane.add(label, 1, 6);
        label = new Label("This is my second label");
        pane.add(label, 1, 7);
        // display circles
        // create two red circles
        circle1 = new Circle(15);
        circle1.setFill(Color.RED);
        circle2 = new Circle(15);
        circle2.setFill(Color.RED);
        // adding circle to pane
        pane.add(circle1, 2, 1);
        pane.add(circle2, 2, 5);
        // display two rectangles
        // create two blue rectangle
        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(20, 20);
        rectangle1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(20, 20);
        rectangle2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        // add rectangle to grid pane
        pane.add(rectangle1, 1, 1);
        pane.add(rectangle2, 1, 4);
        // display 2 pictures
        // get image 1
        Image image1 = new Image("rectangles.png");
        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image1);
        imageView1.setFitWidth(50);
        imageView1.setFitHeight(50);

        // image 2
        Image image2 = new Image("circles.png");
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image2);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(50);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(50);

        // add images to grid pane
        pane.add(imageView1, 2, 12);
        pane.add(imageView2, 3, 10);

        /// show scene
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You may find this helpful [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse)

Comment: spelling error? the module name is `javafx.controls` (note the plural) - could be your typing here, though, never type anything on-the-fly, always c&p actual text. anyway, follow the tutorial referenced by @c0der - it's guranteed to work